# Casting classes inside JavaScript when Interacting with Java

Tags: javascript, java, casting

So I'm working on a Java application game that interacts with JavaScript. Java objects and being passed as parameters into JavaScript methods that interact with them.

I'm curious if it's possible to cast a Java object to another from within a JavaScript method.

For an example, this Java class:

```
Fruit is implemented by Apple.
Fruit is passed into the function 

function process(food) {
}

Is it possible to cast food to Apple from within JavaScript?
```

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Javascript is a dynamic language, you can already use `food` as an `Apple`.

Comment: @JornVernee Wait. I'm unsure of what you mean. Does that mean it will autocast?

Comment: you no need to cast it. since there is no type in javascript.

Comment: @jos Thanks so much! Everything worked out. Wow!